# React Build returns "TypeError" on Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I run my application on localhost, either non-optimal (`npm start`) or optimal (`npm run build && npm start`) and both ways it works just fine.

When I optimize the app and containerize it, provides a white screen with error code:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')`

Non-optimal version of the app works fine in the container, however is not ideal.
What am I doing wrong?

Dockerfile:

```
# stage 1
FROM node:15.4 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#stage 2
FROM nginx:1.19
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

[Build version of the app if you want to try yourself](https://github.com/kadir651/split)